# Appcenter CodePush CLI - list deployments

Tags: cordova, code-push, visual-studio-app-center

I'm a user of CodePush (with cordova).  I'm doing some quick checking into AppCenter since [CodePush is migrating there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/migrationguide).  I'm noticing that the AppCenter CLI doesn't seem as robust/ready as the CodePush CLI.

My main question at this point is if this command should show a deployment history (including old CodePush deployments)?

`appcenter codepush deployment list -a owner/appName`

I'm seeing that it only shows the deployment keys for the app, yet [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/cli) makes it seem like this should also show deployment history.  I'm trying to use the CLI help ([as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/migrationguide)), but this throws an error:
`appcenter codepush help`.

I logged onto the AppCenter UI, and it does show my old CodePush release history.  I would expect the same from the CLI.  I'm guessing I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 2):

You should use 
`appcenter codepush  deployment history <deployementName>` command to show the list of your recent releases (deployment history).

to use help you should prefix `help` arg with double dashes, e.g. `appcenter codepush --help`.

Comment: Thanks!  Both of these tips help a lot.  Seems like the online docs should have `--help` (it lacks the 2 dashes online).  One remaining question: does `appcenter codepush deployment list -a owner/appName` give install metrics for you?  That's the one part I'm missing.

Comment: I believe this part (install metrics) is still not migrated, you can always use old CodePush CLI for this.

Comment: This only worked after I set the app environment variable using `appcenter apps set-current <username>/<app name>`