# CodePush CLI Migration (to AppCenter)

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, code-push, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I currently use [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) for my Cordova app.  Love it.  Microsoft is moving it to AppCenter, and here's the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/migrationguide).

The migration guide notes that the old CLI will be retired in October 2018:

> we are commited to maintain the CLI through September 2018. You are free to continue using the CLI, but all features besides release and viewing metrics will be disabled in Late March 2018. Finally, the CodePush CLI will be retired in Mid October 2018.

My question is if this plan is still accurate?  I know the original plan was to make a new Cordova SDK in February 2018, which was pushed back and no ETA is known.  Is the old CodePush CLI still going to be retired in October?  From what I can tell core things (like getting [install metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345366/appcenter-codepush-cli-list-deployments)) are still not available in the new CLI.  I really don't want to use the AppCenter CLI for some things and log into the AppCenter UI for others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a new CodePush SDK is going to be made available. It is also not on their roadmap:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/roadmap

This image used to be on the AppCenter website showing that the CLI will be deprecated starting with reduced functionality in favor of the AppCenter UI.

[image: AppCenter migration timeline]

Comment: Regarding the SDK, the timeline you note was taken down per this SO post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079892/6599076.  Their migration guide I linked to above also states "No changes in your code will be neccesarry until the release of the new SDK, which currently has no ETA."  So they seem to plan for a new SDK, but no ETA yet.  The focus of this question is the CLI.  Again, they claim the old will be retired in October, but the new CLI is missing functionality, so I wasn't sure if that timeline is also untrustworthy.  If it is, will this missing functionality be added?